# Using Column Name as Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

how do I use a Column Name as Range in VBA I use the below code (CTTO) for conditional formatting, however I manually indicated the range. THis time I need to use the column name as there will be multiple tables that I want to apply conditional formatting to.

```
    'Definining the variables:
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim condition1 As FormatCondition, condition2 As FormatCondition, condition3 As FormatCondition


 'Fixing/Setting the range on which conditional formatting is to be desired
  Set rng = Range("M5", "M16")


  'To delete/clear any existing conditional formatting from the range
   rng.FormatConditions.Delete


  'Defining and setting the criteria for each conditional format
   Set condition1 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=""""")
   Set condition2 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, "=report2!$K$1")
   Set condition3 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlLess, "=report2!$K$1")

   rng.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
   rng.FormatConditions(1).SetFirstPriority
   rng.FormatConditions(2).StopIfTrue = False
   rng.FormatConditions(3).StopIfTrue = False

   'Defining and setting the format to be applied for each condition
   With condition2
    .Font.Color = -16383844
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.TintAndShade = 0
    .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Interior.Color = 13551615
    .Interior.TintAndShade = 0
   End With

   With condition3
    .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.TintAndShade = 0
    .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .Interior.TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
   End With
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean?  In your `Range("M5", "M16")` statement, you are using `M` as the column name. If you mean something else, please be more specific.

Comment: Column have no name (but you may to refer to it by its letter or its number, like  `Columns("B:D").Select` or `Columns("2:4").Select`). Maybe you mean a cell value in some pre-defined row as a marker for a column which you need?

Comment: If `Set rng = Range("M5", "M16")` means you need to format all cells between M5 and M16 inclusive you must use `Set rng = Range("M5:M16")`.

Comment: @Akina - That's incorrect. `Range("M5", "M16")` is **exactly** the same as `Range("M5:M16")`. It's `Range("M5, M16")` that is only M5 and M16 with nothing in between.

Comment: @Jazz H since U are using Table then use this,,,                   
 `Set rngAddress = Range("A1:Z1").Find("Address") Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Select` .You may adjust `A1:Z1` and use Variable for any reason.